# How to give a Jerk Effect when the player is moving left of right

Tags: unity

```
float amttomove = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * playerspeed * Time.deltaTime;
            transform.Translate (Vector3.right * amttomove);
```

Currently, I have above script in Update function to move the object to left or right.But this movement is way smoother.To give it more realistic feel, I want it to have a slight jerk when it stops moving to left or right and not just stop right there and then.

What exactly needs to be done to have that effect?

Comment: If you understand the distinction between acceleration and velocity, this question seems like it should resolve itself.

Comment: I don't agree that his understanding of acceleration and velocity has anything to do with this at all. To help others provide useful answers/comments you need to give some more background. Are you moving a rigidbody? Are you moving a transform? Do you want the jerk to affect movement or is it a visual effect? Stuff like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting velocity("amttomove") to Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * playerSpeed * Time.deltaTime; just add it continuously until it's less than max velocity. e.g.

```
float hr = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

//Accelerate
if (hr != 0 && Mathf.Abs(playerVelocity) < maxVelocity)
{
    playerVelocity += hr * acceleration * Time.deltaTime;
}

//Deaccelerate
if (Mathf.Abs(playerVelocity) > 0)
{
   playerVelocity = Mathf.MoveTowards(playerVelocity, 0, friction * Time.deltaTime);
}

transform.Translate(Vector3.right * playerVelocity);
```

Tweak the values of acceleration and friction to get the desired effect.

Comment: It worked like Magic. Thanks a ton. But what I realize is it moves relatively faster to right than to left.Why exactly is that?Could you please explain, I am quite a newbie and do not understand the semantics so well.

Comment: "moves relatively faster to right than to left"..? That should not happen. Maybe you are getting that feeling because of the orientation of your camera. As for when you change direction it takes some ticks to nullify your current velocity and accelerate in the opposite direction. Deceleration from friction also contributes to halt the object in motion.

Comment: Okay, if that is not so, the car always moves to right 'on its own' and moves to left when I press left arrow.why exactly is that?

Comment: Could you please share the code you have written and provide more information.

Answer (score 3):

The answer from 2600th already outlines how to smooth out your movement by using acceleration an deceleration.

From your question I understood that you not only want a smooth, realistic change but also a little jerk at the end (so first going a little beyond the target and then coming back to it, so that the position "wiggles" a bit). This is commonly revered to as "[easing](https://www.google.de/search?q=easing)".

To do this there are various easing curves from which you need to choose one to implement.

This website outlines and visualizes some of the easing/"jerking" curves (although the code is for CSS/JS) the same curves of course can used in other areas too: http://easings.net/

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161465/how-to-create-custom-easing-function-with-core-animation) also has some curves visualized:
[image]

*Robert Penner* additionally created sample code for various easing methods (in several programming languages) that can be found on [this website](http://robertpenner.com/easing/) along with on online easing formula generation tool.